# Как сократить время сборки проекта

Tags: java, android

Добавил несколько библиотек, в проект после чего сборка начала занимать заметно больше времени. Конкретно, три последних библиотеки. Есть ли возможность как то настроить конфигурацию сборки так, что бы сократилось время сборки.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar')

    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.5'
    compile files('libs/autobahn-0.5.0.jar') 
}
```

Comment: Мне помогли два способа: Врубить Offline Mode и установить Ubuntu.

Comment: @jangorussia а offline mode где вырубить, и что это за режим?

Comment: Справа в Android Studio есть вкладка Gradle -> Иконка  в виде ключа(Найстройки) - > В ней ты найдешь CheckBox "Offline Mode"(Обычно стоит  по дефаулту). Link: http://android-helper.com.ua/android-studio-offline/